# Issue when more than one user tries to connect to my NodeMCU

Tags: session, lua, webserver, nodemcu

I'm working on a little project using Lua and a NodeMCU board but I'm pretty a newbie to the both of the topics and I'm having some troubles.

I have a button attached to the device and what I want to do is basically a manual authentication. After a user has connected to the server on the nodeMCU he will receive a control page where he has to press the button, refresh the page and see the web page i have loaded on the device.

The issue I'm having right now, it's after one user has pressed the button, every new user connecting to the server will totally skip the first phase and connect directly to the web page.

I have been trying some solutions but none of them really worked. I was thinking about initializing a string after one user pressed the button that could work as some sort of session token but I have no idea if that can really work.
Is there any easier solution?

Here is my code so far:

auth.lua

```
srv=net.createServer(net.TCP)
srv:listen(80,function(conn)
    conn:on("receive", function(client,request)

    local buf = "";
    local _, _, method, path, vars = string.find(request, "([A-Z]+) (.+)?(.+) HTTP");
    if(method == nil)then
        _, _, method, path = string.find(request, "([A-Z]+) (.+) HTTP");
    end
    local _GET = {}
    if (vars ~= nil)then
        for k, v in string.gmatch(vars, "(%w+)=(%w+)&*") do
            _GET[k] = v
        end
    end
    buf=buf.."<html><body>"
    buf = buf.."<h1> Control Web Server</h1>";
    buf=buf.."<p> Press the button attached to the device and click below</p>"
    buf=buf.."<p><button onclick=\"history.go(0)\">ADVANCE</button></p>"
    buf = buf.."</form></body></html>"

    local _on,_off = "",""

    gpio.mode(1 ,gpio.INPUT,gpio.PULLUP)

    function debounce (func)
        local last = 0
        local delay = 200000

        return function (...)
            local now = tmr.now()
            if now - last < delay then return end

            last = now
            return func(...)
            end
    end

    function onChange()  
        if gpio.read(1) == 0 then
    assert(loadfile("server.lua"))
            tmr.delay(500000)
            end
end


gpio.trig(1,"down", debounce(onChange))

    client:send(buf);
    client:close();
    collectgarbage();
    end)
end)
```

server.lua

```
srv:listen(80,function(conn)
conn:on("receive", function(client,payload)
       tgtfile = string.sub(payload,string.find(payload,"GET /")
       +5,string.find(payload,"HTTP/")-2)
    if tgtfile == "" then tgtfile = "index.htm" end  

    local f = file.open(tgtfile,"r")
    if f ~= nil then
        client:send(file.read())
        file.close()
    else
        client:send("<html>"..tgtfile.." not found - 404 error.<BR><a href='index.htm'/<%= @a %>>Home</a><BR>")
    end
    client:close();
    collectgarbage();
    f = nil
    tgtfile = nil
end)
end)
```

Comment: What version of NodeMCU are you using?

Comment: The board is the devkit 1.0.
I'm using a custom firmware 1.5.4.1

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is that the `srv:listen()` in your server.lua that is loaded in the onChange function is also on port 80. The `srv:listen()` in `auth.lua` no longer gets called because they are both on port 80, so the newer `listen()` takes over instead.

You'll have to write your code somehow to all be in the same `srv:listen()` function, and store something about the client (their IP, or a cookie, or something) in an array instead.